# Calculating the movement frequency of a metal rode

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, frequency

We have a car with acceleration $a > 0$.

On the top of the car theres a metal rode with weight = $M$ and length = $L$, and the rode is balanced at some angel $\theta$ as can be seen here:

[image: car with rode]

The metal rode moment of inertia is $I = \frac{1}{12}ML^2$.

I am trying to calculate the movement frequency of the metal rode around the balance point.

The frequency formula is $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$.

According to the answers the frequency should be $\sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{g^2+a^2}}{2L}}$.

How did they got from $\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$ to $\sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{g^2+a^2}}{2L}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to understand from the reference frame of the moving car. Since this reference frame is accelerated (with respect to the reference frame of the ground) all objects in this frame experience a force $-m \vec{a}$ and can be understood to be the reason the rod is at an inclination $\theta_0$ to the vertical.

Now the net force on the rod due to gravity and the above mentioned force is (in magnitude) given by $F=m\sqrt{a^2+g^2}$. This is along the rod in its equilibrium position.

For a small angular displacement (say $\theta$) the rod experiences a net torque (about the hinge) $$\tau =-F\cdot\frac{L}{2}\cdot\sin(\theta)\approx -m\sqrt{a^2+g^2}\cdot\frac{L}{2}\cdot\theta$$

where the negative sign indicates the torque is in the opposite sense as the angular displacement. This gives
$$I_\text{hinge}\cdot\alpha=\frac{mL^2}{3}\alpha=-m\sqrt{a^2+g^2}\cdot\frac{L}{2}\cdot\theta$$
$$\implies \alpha=-\frac{3\sqrt{a^2+g^2}}{2L}\cdot\theta$$
Applying simple harmonic concepts now yields $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{a^2+g^2}}{2L}}$ as desired.